# Hover on Image control like facebook picture in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, image

I have an image control on ASPX page. I want to show "Change Picture" option on top it like Facebook. When click on it should go different page.

[image]

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: You can't do this with C# alone, you will need javascript ... check out the jQuery .hover function: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: You can probably do this with pure CSS..

Comment: To be fair, if you have Firebug or Chrome or anything like those inspectors, you can find out exactly how they do it, CSS and all.

Comment: What version of ASP.Net are you using?

Answer (score 1):

May be this is some thing you want:

http://demo.fearlessflyer.com/html/demo/pretty-hovers/

http://thirdroute.com/projects/captify/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #profile_pic_wrapper{ position:relative; border:#ccc solid 1px; width:200px; height:200px;}
        #profile_pic_wrapper a{ position:absolute; display:none; top:0; right:0; line-height:20px; padding:5px; color:#fff; background-color:#333; text-decoration:underline;}
        #profile_pic_wrapper:hover a{ display:block; }
        #profile_pic_wrapper:hover a:hover{text-decoration:none;}
        .profile_pic{ width:200px; height:200px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div id="profile_pic_wrapper">
            <asp:Image ID="imgProfilePic" runat="server" ImageUrl="profile.jpg" CssClass="profile_pic"/>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkChangePicture" runat="server" NavigateUrl="ChangeProfilePic.aspx">Change Picture</asp:HyperLink>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

In the above example, I've included the css styles in aspx page for illustrative purpose only. For real world implementation, it is always recommended to have your styles in a separate css file.

Comment: The above code works fine on firefox, chrome, safari, opera and IE7. This does not work on IE6. For IE6 support you have to do it using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a how-to here http://www.dreamweavertutorial.co.uk/dreamweaver/articles/transparent-layer-overlay.htm

They are called overlays.

Another example here

http://css-tricks.com/3118-text-blocks-over-image/

Answer (score 0):

You would need some client-side code to actually manage the mouseover event and then to show the overlayed A tag (with the text/image you want)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the imagebutton in a div and tie jquery handlers to show or hide the link.

**Edit**: Here is a ***simple*** example:

```
<head runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">    
    <div id="mynamediv" style="width: 50px;">   
        <div id="mydiv" style="display: none;"><a href="www.google.com">Change Image</a></div>
        <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="myimage" ImageUrl="~/myimage.gif" /> 
    </div>
    </form>
<script language="javascript">
    $("#mynamediv").mouseover(function () {
        $("#mydiv").show();   
    });

    $("#mynamediv").mouseout(function () {
        $("#mydiv").hide();
    });
</script>
```

Here's a balloon tip you might like

http://file.urin.take-uma.net/jquery.balloon.js-Demo.html

Comment: Can I have with full detailed example?